# Fetch nested embedded data using mongo mapper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

`temp = Users.where("posts.comments.id"=>"4de5fdc71d41c824b200005c")`

Here 'Users' is the model mongo mapper document

And Posts,Comments are mongo mapper embedded document.

Its like

> Users -> Posts -> Comments

Comments embedded document has four fields. Which are id, message, created_at, updated_at

I just need to get that particular comment data in to a ruby variable.

`temp = Users.where("posts.comments.id"=>"4de5fdc71d41c824b200005c")`

When I am doing this i am getting the outer document Users

I just need only the particular Comments data

Answer (score 0):

You need [$slice](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields):

```
db.users.find({"posts.comments.id":"4de5fdc71d41c824b200005c"}, 
              {posts.comments:{$slice: 1}}) // first matched comment
```

But i am not sure if it work with two level arrays(user->posts->comments) embedding.